# Why does sass fail to compile with grunt command error of "index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for `nth'"?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

After inheriting a project using Grunt, I am running grunt via terminal, waiting for the 'Watching...' make the change to the scss, and terminal recognizes the change but the compilation fails in the next step of compass:dev. Here is what it's showing inside terminal:

```
Waiting...
>> File "../sass/inside.scss" changed.

Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
unchanged ../img/common/1x-scb9effd9a6.png
unchanged ../img/common/2x-s7bf9cb0f59.png
    error /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Repos/wp-content/themes/quindo/_/sass/inside.scss (Line 39 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Repos/wp-content/themes/quindo/_/sass/vendor/retina/_sprite.scss: List index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for `nth')

Compilation failed in 1 files.
```

A. So I look at line 39 of ...vendor/retina/_sprite.scss which is the @if line of the following function and found that the function contains $index: 2. What would be the purpose of setting it to 2?

```
@mixin retina-sprite($name, $sprite-name: 0, $hover: false, $active: false) {
  $index: 2;
  $len: length($retina-sprite-names);

  @for $i from $index through $len {
    @if $sprite-name == nth($retina-sprite-names, $i) {
      $index: $i;
    }
  }

  $sprite       : nth($retina-sprite-sprites, $index);
  $sprite-url   : nth($retina-sprite-urls, $index);

  $sprite2x     : nth($retina-sprite-sprites2x, $index);
  $sprite-url2x : nth($retina-sprite-urls2x, $index);

  @include _retina-sprite($name, $sprite, $sprite-url, $sprite2x, $sprite-url2x, $hover, $active);
}
```

B. To get the scss to change to css, do I simply change the aforementioned 2 to 1? I don't fully understand the effects of the statement.

B2. I tested this theory of changing 2 to 1, and receive errors about the sprite-position() must be a sprite map. Should I simply attempt to run grunt from the development server, wait for 'watching...' then upload the changed .scss file in the thought that the developer was running grunt from the development server rather than locally?

B3. It seems it was built on: https://github.com/novascreen/Retina-mixins-for-Compass/blob/master/src/retina/_retina-sprite.scss

Comment: Is this mixin created by a 3rd party?  If so, you'll want to file a bug report.  The error is referring to the use of `nth()` on the following line.  It is attempting to select the 2nd element of a list that only contains 1 element.  I don't see a reason why they would want to start at the 2nd element, though, so changing it to 1 might cause undesirable side effects.

Comment: It is created by a 3rd party, sounds like I can shoot them an email.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say that this mixin was written for Sass 3.2 or possibly 3.3.  There's no indication here as to what `$retina-sprite-names` is supposed to be, so I am guessing that they're trying to access a variable that exists outside of the scope of this mixin (ie. global).  Scoping changed in Sass 3.4, so global variables aren't visible within mixins unless explicitly specified.

Comment: I think you're right, it was added about 4 months ago and could have been recycled code at that point. I downloaded my local files recently, what do you recommend I do? Is it possible to run grunt on the development server, wait for watching... then upload an edited scss and have it compile it there?

However, $retina-sprite-names     : 0;

Comment: See if this helps get you on the right track:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/d7239fdaba9bcebad2be.  I don't have access to all of the variables/mixins necessary to do the entire thing, so I commented those out (they should work for you if you uncomment them).  If it works, I will post an answer, though I suspect this would be better solved using mappings rather than lists.

Comment: I see where you're going, but it doesn't seem to solve it. I've found what it was built on: 
https://github.com/novascreen/Retina-mixins-for-Compass/blob/master/src/retina/_retina-sprite.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, the mixin is attempting to call the 2nd element of a list that only has 1 element in it.  This is because this mixin (and its related mixins) were written for an older version of Sass where mixins and functions freely had access to global variables.  To remedy this, you'll need to add the `!global` flag to any instance where the global variable is being referenced.

This is an issue throughout the entire library, it isn't isolated to just the mixin provided by the OP.  I've cleaned up the related `retina-sprite-add()` mixin so that you can see what needs to be changed and carry it over to the rest of the mixins.

The Original:

```
$retina-sprite-names     : 0;
$retina-sprite-sprites   : 0;
$retina-sprite-urls      : 0;
$retina-sprite-sprites2x : 0;
$retina-sprite-urls2x    : 0;

@mixin retina-sprite-add($name, $path, $path2x) {
  $retina-sprite-spacing: 2px !default;

  $sprite   : sprite-map($path, $spacing: $retina-sprite-spacing);
  $sprite2x : sprite-map($path2x, $spacing: $retina-sprite-spacing);

  $retina-sprite-names     : append($retina-sprite-names, $name);

  $retina-sprite-sprites   : append($retina-sprite-sprites, $sprite);
  $retina-sprite-urls      : append($retina-sprite-urls, sprite-url($sprite));

  $retina-sprite-sprites2x : append($retina-sprite-sprites2x, $sprite2x);
  $retina-sprite-urls2x    : append($retina-sprite-urls2x, sprite-url($sprite2x));
}
```

Updated for 3.4:

```
$retina-sprite-names     : 0;
$retina-sprite-sprites   : 0;
$retina-sprite-urls      : 0;
$retina-sprite-sprites2x : 0;
$retina-sprite-urls2x    : 0;

@mixin retina-sprite-add($name, $path, $path2x) {
  $retina-sprite-spacing: 2px !default;

  $sprite   : sprite-map($path, $spacing: $retina-sprite-spacing);
  $sprite2x : sprite-map($path2x, $spacing: $retina-sprite-spacing);

  $retina-sprite-names     : append($retina-sprite-names, $name) !global;

  $retina-sprite-sprites   : append($retina-sprite-sprites, $sprite) !global;
  $retina-sprite-urls      : append($retina-sprite-urls, sprite-url($sprite)) !global;

  $retina-sprite-sprites2x : append($retina-sprite-sprites2x, $sprite2x) !global;
  $retina-sprite-urls2x    : append($retina-sprite-urls2x, sprite-url($sprite2x)) !global;
}

@include retina-sprite-add('foo', 'foo.png', 'foox2.png');
@include retina-sprite-add('bar', 'bar.png', 'barx2.png');

.foo {
  debug: $retina-sprite-names;
}
```

Should now output:

```
.foo {
  debug: 0 "foo" "bar";
}
```

Of course, this also explains why the `$index` variable starts with the 2nd index.

Comment: I love you cimmanon. You solved my week's problem. Big high five for you.

Comment: For any other who runs into this, simply repalce the @mixin retina-sprite-add function with his above (stop at bracket before @include).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access 2nd element of a list that only contains one element hence the compiler throws an error.

Comment: Since I'm on a test server, should I just change it to 1?

Comment: While this explains the error, it doesn't explain *why* there is an error in the first place.

Comment: Its difficult to comment since i dont have the full code infront of me. what is `$retina-sprite-names`, `$retina-sprite-sprites`, etc?

Comment: Changed it to one, and now it's letting me know: The first argument to sprite-position() must be a sprite map.

The first argument is:
@import "compass/utilities/sprites"

But I can't seem to locate that file.