# Updating a mixin for themes with SASS 3.4.7

Tags: sass, mixins

I updated today SASS to use the version **3.4.7** Unfortunetly, one mixin I used since the beginning of my project don't work anymore. I don't understand why...

```
$program: test1;

@mixin program($programName) {
  @each $p in $programName {
    @if $p == $program {
        @content;
    }
  }
}

$cta-box-type: null !default;

@include program(test1) {
  $cta-box-type: cta-buy, cta-like;
}

@include program(test2) {
  $cta-box-type: cta-like, cta-share;
}

@each $cta-type in $cta-box-type {
    .banner--#{$cta-type} .banner {
      background: white image-url("Modules/Cta/bg-#{$cta-type}-1.jpg") no-repeat bottom left;
      background-size: 100% auto;
    }
}
```

[DEMO SASSMEISTER](http://sassmeister.com/gist/de068a9cef2c1a8620e3)

The compiled result looks like this:

```
.banner-- .banner {
  background: white url('/images/Modules/Cta/bg--1.jpg') no-repeat bottom left;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Instead of:

```
.banner--cta-buy .banner {
  background: white url('/images/Modules/Cta/bg-cta-buy-1.jpg') no-repeat bottom left;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.banner--cta-like .banner {
  background: white url('/images/Modules/Cta/bg-cta-like-1.jpg') no-repeat bottom left;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

If someone have an idea why it's no more working, it's gone help me a lot !
Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sass fail to compile with grunt command error of "index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for \`nth'"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637848/why-does-sass-fail-to-compile-with-grunt-command-error-of-index-is-2-but-list-i)

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon, your link helped me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

I simply removed the !default and add !global.

```
$cta-box-type: null;

@include program(test1) {
  $cta-box-type: cta-buy, cta-like !global;
}

@include program(test2) {
  $cta-box-type: cta-like, cta-share !global;
}
```